# Confusion with tracing current flow, and finding voltage of 2mA current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit

Where there is a question mark, does the current flow there?

Also, why does current travels through the 6Kohm resistor, and it doesn't all go to the 2mA source?

Lastly, how would you go about with finding the voltage of the 2mA or 2Kohm source if no current goes to the 2Kohm resistor?

[image]

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. because there's a voltage across it; 3. your premise is wrong

Comment: I'm confused with why current flows through the 6Kohm resistor; I was taught that current takes the path with the least resistance.

Comment: Update: FORGOT THAT A CURRENT SOURCE ALSO HAS A VOLTAGE.